# How to Write ActiveRecord Query For Special Case

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 5.1, and I have an `Entry` model that has a `word` attribute. There can be multiple `Entries` with the same word, as their uniqueness is based on `word` plus another field. In the controller, I am creating a dropdown selector `@unique_entries` that should only include the first instance of an `Entry.word`.

I have attempted to do this from multiple angles, but just can't seem to get it right.

The last thing I tried was something like this pseudocode (sorry, I deleted the actual code after it failed):

```
all_entries = Entry.all.order(word: :asc)
unique_entries = []
all_entries.each do |entry|
  if unique_entries.include?(entry.word)
    use the index to delete this record from all_entries
  else
    unique_entries << entry.word
  end
end
```

In my head at least, this should loop through the `all_entries` collection, checking to see if each `entry.word` is in `unique_entries`, which starts out as an empty array. If not, the `entry.word` gets added to `unique_entries`. If so, it removes the `entry` from the ActiveRecord collection `all_entries`, because that means one already exists. This approach failed hard, removing contents from a sample array inconsistently.

I realize this is a slow way to go, and will only be fine while I have a small number of records, so I am open to suggestions of other ways to approach this. I am still relatively new to RoR development and haven't had to deal with very complex ActiveRecord queries yet, so please don't step on my neck for not having already done what would have been "obvious" to you. Thanks.

Comment: I included the `sql` tag on this question because I know Rails can use plain SQL queries, if needed, and I am open to that if it gets the job done.

Comment: I should also mention that the instance variable `@unique_entries` has nothing to do with the empty array of the same name in the block.

Comment: You don't have an instance variable `@unique_entries` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can let the database do the work by using `distinct` and `pluck` together:

```
Entry.distinct.pluck(:word)
```

And if you want the database to do the sorting:

```
Entry.distinct.order(:word).pluck(:word)
```

The last one should end up using SQL like this:

```
select distinct word from entries order by word
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@unique_entries = Entry.pluck(:word).uniq
```

Or:

```
@unique_entries = Entry.all.order(word: :asc).pluck(:word).uniq
```

To have it sorted.

To be a bit more descriptive, consider:

```
@unique_entry_words = Entry.all.order(word: :asc).pluck(:word).uniq
```

(since the array is, well, a set of unique entry words, not unique entries)

Of course, mu is too short is correct and this would be better as:

```
Entry.distinct.order(:word).pluck(:word)
```

If, OTOH, you're trying to get an array comprised of the first instance of each `Entry` for a given `word` (not sure if that's what you're after, but that comment about 'use the index to delete...' suggests it might be), you could try something like:

```
Entry.all.order(:word).group_by(&:word).map{|k,v| v.first}
```

Comment: even better: `Entry.distinct.pluck(:word)` (the uniqueness job will be done by the DB, which is wayyyyy faster than Ruby's `Array#uniq` method)

Comment: @MrYoshiji Except you don't actually need the `select(:word)` part. But yeah, let the database do the work.